# Building libraries for both web, android, and ios using Nativescript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, nativescript

I want to build a client-side library for web, android, and ios. I thought Nativescript would allow this but my searches only yield references to Android and iOS builds.  Is it possible to do this with Nativescript?  Other suggestions are welcome.  Thanks!

Comment: Separate out the common code into a core project, and link that project to both your NativeScript library and your web library (e.g. via `npm link`). There's no way to directly output a web-compatible build of your NativeScript library if that's what you're asking, at least not that I know of.

Comment: @arao6 your reply gave me more areas for research and is appreciated.  thank you.